# How to list *all* running time sync services

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I have an Ubuntu box and I wish to set up an NTP time sync. Decided to go with `chrony`.  I want to make sure no other out-of-box time sync service is running.

I ran `sudo service --status-all` and none of the services pop out. But is there a more thorough method to check there are no time syncs running? The reason I'm not satisfied is that `timedatectl` *was* running, yet it produces no visible service in the list above- well, nothing resembling "timedatectl" anyway.

```
John:~$ timedatectl
  Local time: Sat 2018-08-18 04:29:15 UTC
  Universal time: Sat 2018-08-18 04:29:15 UTC
  RTC time: Sat 2018-08-18 04:29:15
  Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
  Network time on: yes
  NTP synchronized: yes
  RTC in local TZ: no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have a look at the `netstat` results and see if anything is bound to the `ntp` port.

By doing `netstat -a` you should get a result similar to this below (truncated);

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State           
udp        0      0 vm0:ntp                     *:*                                     
udp        0      0 localhost.localdomain:ntp   *:*                                     
udp        0      0 *:ntp                       *:*                                     
udp        0      0 fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ntp *:*                                     
udp        0      0 localhost.localdomain:ntp   *:*                                     
udp        0      0 *:ntp                       *:*
```

Look out for the lines with 'ntp' or anything bound to port 123. That will tell you that you have something running and active. I can't see a quick command which allows you to check which program or process is bound to a *port* (But you can see what's created a socket with `-p` to see the PID & program name)